# Having trouble with selectedrowincomponenet function in swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I am having a problem with the selected row in component I have a picker view with  2 components and 5 rows I want it to convert units. the trouble is when I try to scroll down the the switch statements don't work. The only one that works is the var second. If I try Hectare -> square Inch it converts it right but if I try Acre -> square inch it gives me the same answer as the hectare -> square Inch .  Also when I add try to add another selectedRowInComponent(2) the app crashes .

```
Acre                    Acre
Hectare                 Hectare
Square Inch             Square Inch     
Square Meter            Square Meter
Square Kilometer        Square Kilometer
Square Foot             Square Foot
```

This is the code I am using

```
    var one: NSInteger = onlyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    var second: NSInteger = onlyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(1)



        switch (one) {



        case 0:

            answerField2.text = answerField1.text




        case 1:



            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 2.4711

            var answer = num1 / num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display



        case 2:



            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 6272600

            var answer = num1 * num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display




        case 3:

            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 0.00023711

            var answer = num1 / num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display

        case 4:

            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 247.11

            var answer = num1 / num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display




        case 5:

            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 43560

            var answer = num1 * num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display




        default:

            println("not a value")



        }
        switch (second) {

        case 0:




            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 2.4711

            var answer = num1 * num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display



        case 1:



            answerField2.text = answerField1.text




        case 2:



            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 15500000

            var answer = num1 / num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display


        case 3:

            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 0.00010000

            var answer = num1 / num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display



        case 4:

            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 100

            var answer = num1 / num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display





        case 5:

            var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

            var num2:Float = 107640

            var answer = num1 * num2

            var display = answer.description

            answerField2.text = display


        default:

            println("not a value")






        }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the crashing issue if it's crashing on code like this, then please check the numberOfComponents property on your UIPicker.    If it's set to 2 - then that that would be the problem.

```
var third: NSInteger = onlyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(2)
```

On the calculations, re-factoring the code as follows will eliminate the switch statements. The conversions variable is an array of array of type Float (using the new Swift style - as of Xcode 6 Beta 3).

I've listed the names of the conversion values to illustrate how to setup / populate the array.   These should be replaced with a Float value.

```
var conversions: [[Float]] = [ [acre-to-acre,acre-to-hectace,acre-to-square-inch,....], 
                               [hectacre-to-acre,hectacre-tohectacre,hectacre-to-square-inch,...],
                               [square-inch-to-acre,square-inch-to-hectacre,...]
                               ....
                             ]


var one: NSInteger = onlyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
var second: NSInteger = onlyPicker.selectedRowInComponent(1)

var num1 = (answerField1.text as NSString).floatValue

var conversionFactor:Float = conversions[one][two]

var answer = num1 * conversionFactor

var display = answer.description

answerField2.text = display
```

Comment: some of the conversions require division what would I do in that case

Comment: You could define your conversion factor as  1 / ConversionFactor, and then multiply that result.